# The logic behind Canva's Magic Resize function?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Thanks a lot for looking over this question!

I was just curious about how one would start looking at how to build this function within a browser. I have a small image editing website and I am looking to implement it and I can't wrap my head around what logic one could write for so many layouts.

For those who don't have context: Canva allows you to create a Facebook post (at some aspect ratio) and then after you finished your design you can resize it to another aspect ratio. During this resizing certain elements behave in different ways (backgrounds shrink or scale up, text layers reposition themselves)

Video example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSTvMOaXdP0

Any extra details that I could give, let me know. Thanks again!

Tibi

Comment: As far as I can tell the algorithm in the youtube video simply changes the background image to the nearest possible resolution and then just cuts top/bottom or left/right to get the correct ratio. The textbox can be adjusted without cropping, cause you can change font-size, boxing etc.

Comment: you can use media query

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you!